# Website is not scrolling and cuts off text depending on aspect ratio

Tags: html, css

I'm having issues where my website will cut off all information at the bottom of the screen and not scroll when at smaller aspect ratios. It will show the image no matter what but will cut the text below it. I have tried using overflow-y and overflow but neither allow scrolling. I'm not sure if it is due to elements being fixed or not but having the elements fixed is the only way I've been able to get them to look right.

Here is the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Aeronaut Travel Agency</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<link rel = "stylesheet" href = "css/travel.css">

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<header>
<h1>Aeronaut Travel Agency</h1>
</header>
<nav>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="VacationPackages.html">Vacation Packages</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Packing.html">Things to Pack</a></li>
        <li><a href="#AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
        <li><a href="#Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>

<main>
    <h2>
        Vacation Packages
    </h2>
    <div>
        <img src="images/LasVegas.png" alt="Las Vegas, seen at night" class="floatleft">
    </div>


    <div class="row">
        <div class="column">
            <h3>
                Visit beautiful, sunny Las Vegas. A wonderland of all kinds of entertainment.
            </h3>
            <p>Want to have dinner and a show, come to the world-famous Caesar's Palace. With hundreds of live shows, thousands of high-end restaurants and the iconic Strip, there is always something fun and new to do in the city that never sleeps. </p> 
            <p> Las Vegas has so many entertainment, dining, shopping, nightlife, golf, and spa options, it can be tough to choose which experiences are perfect for your trip. That’s where we come in. Visit Vegas with Aeronaut Travel Agency.</p>
            <br class="clear">
        </div>
        <div class="column">
            <h3><i>Top Attractions</i></h3>
            <ul>
                <p></p>
                <li>
                    Mystere by Cirque du Solie
                </li>
                <li>
                    Vegas! The Show
                </li>
                <li>
                    The Strip
                </li>
                <li>
                    Venetian Gondolas
                </li>
                <li>
                    Madame Tussaud’s
                </li>
                <li>
                    Las Vegas Motor Speedway
                </li>
            </ul>
            <h3><i>Top Hotels</i></h3>
            <ul>
                <p></p>
                <li>The Venetian</li>
                <li>The Bellagio</li>
                <li>Caesar’s Palace Hotel & Casino</li>
                <li>The Luxor Casino & Hotel</li>
                <li>Mandalay Bay</li>
                <li>The MGM Grand</li>
                <li>Excalibur Hotel & Casino</li>
            </ul>
            <br class="clear">
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
<footer>
<small><i>Copyright &copy; </i> 2020 Aeronaut Travel Agency Inc, <i>All rights Reserved<br>
</i></small>
</footer>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the CSS

```
HTML {
    height: 100%;
    margin: auto;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

header, nav, main, footer {
    display: block;
}

body {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    color: #000000;
    font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    overflow-y: auto;
}

header {
    background-color: #9DC3E6;
    background-image: url(../images/Logo.png);
    background-size: contain; 
    background-position-x: 35px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

h1 {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-left: 7.5em;
    color: #F2F2F2;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #656565;
    font-style: italic;
}

h2 {
    color: #2E75B6;
    font-style: italic;

}

h3 {
    font-style: italic;
}

nav {
    display: inline;
    padding: 0em;
    width: 160px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 150px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 100%;
}

    nav a {
        text-decoration: none;
        display: block;
        text-align: center;
        padding: .8em;
    }

        nav a:link {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        nav a:visited {
            color: #FFFFFF;
        }

        nav a:hover {
            color: #C8C8C8;
        }

    nav ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color: #1F4E79;
        list-style-type: none;
    }

    nav li {
        border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
        float: left;
        padding-left: 10px;
        padding-right: 10px;
    }

li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
li:first-child {
    padding-left: 40px;
}

nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
    background-color: #1360A6;
}

#active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
}


.studio {
    font-style: italic;
}

footer {
    background-color: #9DC3E6;
    font-size: small;
    font-style: italic;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 1em;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}

main {
    padding-left: 2em;
    padding-right: 2em;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 170px;
    width: 1550px;
    padding-top: 1em;
    position: fixed;
    top:175px;
}

.floatleft {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 4em;
}

.clear {
    clear: both;
}

img 
{
    width: auto;
    position:relative;
}

#hero-image {
    background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../images/Hero.jpg);
    height: 50%;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    position: fixed;
}

.hero-text {
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
    color: white;
}

.column {
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
}

.row:after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    padding: 1em;
}


#wrapper {
    width: 100%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

Any advice on this is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should refrain from using the property "fixed" because as the documentation says here: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp.

The fixed property implies that elements with this property don't move no matter what, even if you scroll down the page. So when you scrolled down, your header didn't move your class called "main" too and such...

---

(This part was corrected, sorry about that but I made mistake but now it's all good !)
**So a solution would be to do this:**

- replace all "position:fixed" by "position: absolute" they are the same, exept 
  that fixed as I said below prevent you from scrolling "normally" your page, see 
  the documentation link above
- Once the previous is done, inside the "wrapper" container you used "position: 
  absolute" which force you to use "position: absolute;" for every element inside 
  wrapper (i am not talking about the childs of these elements, just the parent)
  As such footer too, which you already did, but you used "bottom:0" to describe 
  it, you should use "top:x px" instead where x is the number you chose to put

Basically, try not to use "fixed" no matter what, unless you want the element to be unmovable.

I tried this solution on my PC and your code works just fine.

HTML :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Aeronaut Travel Agency</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "website-is-not-scrolling-and-cuts-off-text-depending-on-aspect-ratio.css">

</head>

<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <header>
            <h1>Aeronaut Travel Agency</h1>
        </header>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="VacationPackages.html">Vacation Packages</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Packing.html">Things to Pack</a></li>
                <li><a href="#AboutUs.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="#Contact.html">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>

        <main>
            <h2>Vacation Packages</h2>
            <div>
                <img src="images/LasVegas.png" alt="Las Vegas, seen at night" class="floatleft">
            </div>


            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <h3>
                        Visit beautiful, sunny Las Vegas. A wonderland of all kinds of entertainment.
                    </h3>
                    <p>Want to have dinner and a show, come to the world-famous Caesar's Palace. With hundreds of live shows, thousands of high-end restaurants and the iconic Strip, there is always something fun and new to do in the city that never sleeps. </p> 
                    <p> Las Vegas has so many entertainment, dining, shopping, nightlife, golf, and spa options, it can be tough to choose which experiences are perfect for your trip. That’s where we come in. Visit Vegas with Aeronaut Travel Agency.</p>
                    <br class="clear">
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <h3><i>Top Attractions</i></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <p></p>
                        <li>
                            Mystere by Cirque du Solie
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Vegas! The Show
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            The Strip
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Venetian Gondolas
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Madame Tussaud’s
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            Las Vegas Motor Speedway
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                    <h3><i>Top Hotels</i></h3>
                    <ul>
                        <p></p>
                        <li>The Venetian</li>
                        <li>The Bellagio</li>
                        <li>Caesar’s Palace Hotel & Casino</li>
                        <li>The Luxor Casino & Hotel</li>
                        <li>Mandalay Bay</li>
                        <li>The MGM Grand</li>
                        <li>Excalibur Hotel & Casino</li>
                    </ul>
                    <br class="clear">
                </div>
            </div>
        </main>
  <footer>
    <small><i>Copyright &copy; </i> 2020 Aeronaut Travel Agency Inc, <i>All         rights Reserved<br>
    </i></small>
  </footer>
    </div>

</body>
```

CSS :

```
        HTML {
        height: 100%;
        margin: auto;
    }

    *{
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    header, nav, main, footer {
        display: block;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #FFFFFF;
        color: #000000;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
        overflow-x:hidden;
        overflow-y: auto;
    }

    header {
        background-color: #9DC3E6;
        background-image: url(../images/Logo.png);
        background-size: contain; 
        background-position-x: 35px;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        height: 150px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

    h1 {
        padding-top: 50px;
        padding-left: 7.5em;
        color: #F2F2F2;
        text-shadow: 2px 2px #656565;
        font-style: italic;
    }

    h2 {
        color: #2E75B6;
        font-style: italic;

    }

    h3 {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    nav {
        display: inline;
        padding: 0em;
        width: 160px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 150px;
        left: 0px;
        width: 100%;
    }

        nav a {
            text-decoration: none;
            display: block;
            text-align: center;
            padding: .8em;
        }

            nav a:link {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            nav a:visited {
                color: #FFFFFF;
            }

            nav a:hover {
                color: #C8C8C8;
            }

        nav ul {
            list-style-type: none;
            margin: 0;
            padding: 0;
            overflow: hidden;
            background-color: #1F4E79;
            list-style-type: none;
        }

        nav li {
            border-right: 1px solid #bbb;
            float: left;
            padding-left: 10px;
            padding-right: 10px;
        }

    li:last-child {
        border-right: none;
    }
    li:first-child {
        padding-left: 40px;
    }

    nav li a:hover:not(.active) {
        background-color: #1360A6;
    }

    #active {
        background-color: #4CAF50;
    }


    .studio {
        font-style: italic;
    }

    footer {
        background-color: #9DC3E6;
        font-size: small;
        font-style: italic;
        text-align: center;
        padding: 1em;
        width: 100%;
        position: absolute;
        top: 1000px;/*here*/
        left:0px;
    }

    main {
        padding-left: 2em;
        padding-right: 2em;
        display: block;
        margin-left: 170px;
        width: 1550px;
        padding-top: 1em;
        position: absolute;
        top:175px;
    }

    .floatleft {
        float: left;
        margin-right: 4em;
    }

    .clear {
        clear: both;
    }

    img 
    {
        width: auto;
        position:relative;
    }

    #hero-image {
        background-image: linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../images/Hero.jpg);
        height: 50%;
        background-position: center;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-size: cover;
        position: absolute;
    }

    .hero-text {
        text-align: center;
        position: absolute;
        top: 50%;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
        color: white;
    }

    .column {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }

    .row:after {
        content: "";
        display: table;
        padding: 1em;
    }


    #wrapper {
        width: 100%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9g0qp2cs/2/

Comment: Can you provide a code example using the website: https://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link in your answer? As you said, it works in your case, but prove it by going to that website and sharing the link.

Answer (score 0):

`<main>` doesn't need to be `position:fixed;` if you want it to scroll with the viewport. Try `position:relative;`.

Add a `z-index: 10` to your `<nav>` and `<header>` elements so when you scroll the text is below the header.